# Change label text from within command proc

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I have already created a TkLabel beforehand and now I want to update its text variable inside a command proc. The only problem is that `NameError: unknown option 'codelabel' for #<Tk::Button:0x00000000050797e8 @path=".w00003"> (deleted widget?)`.

It seems it is unable to reference the label variable from within the command proc. 
Is this the right way to assign?

```
TkButton.new(root){
    text "GET"
    #command proc { p txthost.value; p txtpath.value;exit }
    command proc{
            rc.get_method(txthost.value,txtpath.value);
            txtcode.value=rc.code;
            txthtml.value=rc.html;
            codelabel.text=txtcode.value  #label text updated here
        }
    pack('side'=>'bottom', 'padx'=>10, 'pady'=>10)
}
```

Any advice?
Forgive me, for the question, I am new to Ruby.

Comment: Please post your *entire* Ruby program. As it is, I get 'uninitialized constant TkButton'.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic context (where it's unable to reference the label variable) isn't the command proc. Instead, unexpectedly, it's the entire code block passed to `TkButton.new`.

Generally speaking, the best way around this problem is to avoid passing a code block to  `TkButton.new` in the first place—as follows:

```rb
b = TkButton.new(root)
b.text "GET"
#command proc { p txthost.value; p txtpath.value;exit }
b.command proc{
  rc.get_method(txthost.value, txtpath.value)
  txtcode.value = rc.code
  txthtml.value = rc.html
  codelabel.text = txtcode.value #label text updated here
}
b.pack('side'=>'bottom', 'padx'=>10, 'pady'=>10)
```